# reledmac : \pstart and \pend with quotation env

Tags: paragraphs, reledmac

Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
% 
\usepackage{polyglossia}
% 
\setdefaultlanguage{sanskrit}
% 
\newfontfamily{\devanagarifont}[%
    Script=Devanagari,
    Ligatures=TeX,
]%
{Adishila}
% 
\usepackage[paperheight=8.3in,paperwidth=5.8in,margin=1in]{geometry}
% 
\usepackage[parapparatus]{reledmac}
% 
\linenummargin{outer}
\lineation{page}
\firstlinenum{1}
\linenumincrement{1}
% 
% I've already added a pstart and pend here.
\newenvironment{chitsukhI}{%
    \fontsize{18}{20}\selectfont%
    \pstart%
}{\pend}
% 
\usepackage[leftmargin = 0pt, rightmargin=0pt, vskip=0pt, indentfirst=false]{quoting}
% 
% 
% 
\begin{document}
% 
% 
% 
\beginnumbering%
%
% 
% 
\begin{chitsukhI}%
    %
    % कार्य्यान्यथानुपपत्तिः न शक्तौ प्रमाणं , प्रतिबन्धकाभावसंवलितसामग्र्या एव कार्य्योत्पत्तिसम्भवात् ।
    \textbf{नाद्यः} ;
    %
    \pend%
    %
    \begin{quoting}%
        %
        \pstart%
        %
        \edtext{स्वरूपादेव पावकादेः}{%
            %\lemma{}%
            \Bfootnote{%
                कारणस्वरूपादेव ।%
            }%
        }
        प्रतिबन्धकाभावादिसहकार्युपबृंहितात् स्फोटादिलक्षणकार्योत्पत्त्युपपत्तौ अतीन्द्रियशक्तिकल्पनानुपपत्तेः ।%
        %
        \pend%
        %
        \begin{quoting}%
            %
            \pstart%
            %
            % प्रतिबन्धकाभावस्याभावत्वं न तन्निष्ठकारणत्वविरोधि , कार्य्यस्य प्रतिबन्धकाभावान्वयव्यतिरेकानुविधायित्वात् , परमते अनुपलब्द्धेः विवेकाग्रहस्य च कार्य्यजनकत्वाङ्गीकारात् ।
            \textbf{न च} --- \edtext{अभावस्य}{%
                %\lemma{}%
                \Bfootnote{%
                    प्रतिबन्धकाभावस्य ।%
                }%
            }
            अकारणत्वात् , प्रतिबन्धकाभावो न \edtext{सहकारी}{%
                %\lemma{}%
                \Bfootnote{%
                    कारणस्य सहकारी ।%
                }%
            }
            --- \textbf{इति साम्प्रतं} ;\\
            किम् \edtext{\textbf{अन्वयव्यतिरेकित्वं}}{%
                %\lemma{}%
                \Bfootnote{%
                    किं प्रतिबन्धकाभावस्य कार्य्यहेतुत्वनिश्चायकं तदन्वये कार्य्यान्वयः तदभावे च कार्य्याभाव इतिरूपम् अन्वयव्यतिरेकित्वं नास्ति ।%
                }%
            }
            \textbf{नास्ति} ;
            उत \edtext{\textbf{अभावस्य कारणत्वेऽनिष्टप्रसक्तिः}}{%
                %\lemma{}%
                \Bfootnote{%
                    प्रतिबन्धकाभावस्य कार्य्यान्वयव्यतिरेकित्वेपि न कारणत्वम् , अनिष्टविशेषप्रसक्तेः इत्याशयो वा ।%
                }%
            }
            ।\\
            \textbf{नाद्यः} ; भाववद् अभावस्यापि कार्यान्वयव्यतिरेकित्वात् ।\\
            \textbf{न द्वितीयः} ; \edtext{योग्यानुपलब्धेः}{%
                %\lemma{}%
                \Bfootnote{%
                    \textbf{योग्यानुपलब्धेः} - इति ।
                    भाट्टानाम् इत्यादि ।\\
                    \textbf{योग्यानुपलब्धेः} = प्रमाऽभावरूपायाः ।%
                }%
            }
            अभावप्रमितिहेतुत्वात् ,
            \edtext{विवेकाग्रहस्य}{%
                %\lemma{}%
                \Bfootnote{%
                    प्राभाकराणाम् इत्यादि ।%
                }%
            }
            च \edtext{विभ्रमहेतुत्वात्}{%
                %\lemma{}%
                \Bfootnote{%
                    तथा च अभावस्यापि कारणत्वस्य परसम्मतत्वात् कथं प्रतिबन्धकाभावस्य हेतुत्वम् अभावत्वावच्छिन्नत्वमात्रेणानिष्टापादकं स्यात् इत्याशयः ।%
                }%
            }
            ।
            %
            \pend%
            % %\par%
            % %
            \pstart%
            %
            % मीमांसकमतेन प्रतिबन्धकप्रागभावध्वंसयोः सहकारिकारणत्वनियतेर्न्निरासः
            \textbf{ननु} ---
            % \begin{quoting}%
            किं \textbf{प्रतिबन्धकप्रागभावस्य कारणत्वम्} , उत \textbf{तत्प्रध्वंसस्य} ।\\
            \textbf{नाद्यः} ; उत्तम्भकसद्भावे सत्यपि प्रतिबन्धके विनापि \edtext{प्रागभावं}{%
                %\lemma{}%
                \Bfootnote{%
                    प्रतिबन्धकप्रागभावम् ।%
                }%
            }
            कार्यदर्शनात् ।\\
            \textbf{न द्वितीयः} ; प्रतिबन्धकानुदयेऽपि कार्योपलब्धेः ।%
            % \end{quoting}%
            - \textbf{इति चेत्} ।
            %
            \pend%
            % %\par%
            % %
            \pstart%
            %
            % तार्क्किकादिमतेन प्रतिबन्धकप्रागभावतद्ध्वंसभावसाधारणस्य प्रतिबन्धकसंसर्ग्गाभावस्य सहकारिकारणत्वम् इति प्रतिबन्धकाभावस्य विशेषपर्य्यवसानम् । तथा च प्रतिबन्धकाभावस्य सहकारिकारणत्वेन नियमो भवति ।
            \textbf{मैवम्} ; उत्तम्भकमणिमन्त्राद्यभावसहकृतस्यैव प्रतिबन्धकस्य प्रतिबन्धकत्वात् ।
            तेन \edtext{तत्र}{%
                %\lemma{}%
                \Bfootnote{%
                    यत्र प्रतिबन्धकत्वाभिमतोत्तम्भकौ वर्त्तेते तत्र प्रतिबन्धकप्रागभावाभावरूपस्य प्रतिबन्धकस्य सद्भावेपि कार्य्योत्पत्तिः दृश्यते इति न प्रतिबन्धकप्रागभावरूपस्य प्रतिबन्धकाभावस्य सहकारिकारणत्वनियम इति मीमांसकेन यदुक्तं ;\\
                    तन्न ; उत्तम्भकसत्त्वे प्रतिबन्धकत्वस्यैवानङ्गीकारात् ।
                    तथा च प्रतिबन्धकरूपस्य प्रतिबन्धकप्रागभावाभावस्य तत्रासत्त्वात् न प्रतिबन्धकसंसर्ग्गाभावस्य सहकारिकारणत्वनियमस्य क्षतिः ।%
                }%
            }
            प्रतिबन्धकप्रागभावसहकृतस्यैव कारणत्वात् न \edtext{व्यभिचारः}{%
                %\lemma{}%
                \Bfootnote{%
                    प्रतिबन्धकप्रागभावो यत्र यत्र तत्र तत्र कार्य्यम् इतिनियमस्य व्यभिचारो न ।%
                }%
            }
            ।
            %
            \pend%
            % %\par%
            % %
            \pstart%
            %
            % प्रतिबन्धकस्य कदाचित् प्रागभाव कारणं कदाचित् तु प्रध्वंसोपि इति अनियतस्यैव अभावस्य कारणता इत्यपि न ; प्रतिबन्धकप्रतियोगिकस्य संसर्ग्गाभावस्यैव हेतुत्वाभ्युपगमात् ।
            \edtext{\textbf{एतेन}}{%
                %\lemma{}%
                \Bfootnote{%
                    प्रतिबन्धकसंसर्ग्गाभावस्यैव सहकारिकारणत्वनियमस्य विवक्षितत्वोक्त्या ।%
                }%
            }
            \edtext{अनियतहेतुकत्वम्}{%
                %\lemma{}%
                \Bfootnote{%
                    प्रतिबन्धकाभावस्य इत्यादि ।%
                }%
            }
            अपि \textbf{अपास्तम्} ;\\
            \textbf{सर्वत्र प्रतिबन्धकसंसर्गाभावविशिष्टस्यैव कारणात्वाङ्गीकारात्} ;
            अन्यथा , \edtext{अनुपलब्धावपि}{%
                %\lemma{}%
                \Bfootnote{%
                    परमते अभावप्रमितिकारणभूते \textbf{उपलब्द्ध्यभावे} = योग्यार्त्थस्य ज्ञानसामान्याभावे ।%
                }%
            }
            उपलब्धिप्रागभावप्रध्वंसाभावविकल्पेन अभावप्रमितेः \edtext{अनियतहेतुकताया}{%
                %\lemma{}%
                \Bfootnote{%
                    तथाहि\\
                    यदा ?????%
                }%
            }
            दुष्परिहरत्वात् ।
            %
            \pend%
            % %\par%
            % % 
            % %
            \pstart%
            %
            शक्तिपक्षेऽप्यप्रतिबद्धाया एव \edtext{तस्याः}{%
                %\lemma{}%
                \Bfootnote{%
                    शक्तेः ।%
                }%
            }
            कारणत्वाद् , अभावविकल्पोत्थदोषतत्परिहारयोः \edtext{समानत्वात्}{%
                %\lemma{}%
                \Bfootnote{%
                    अस्य हेतुत्वेन ...... इत्यत्रान्वयः ।?????%
                }%
            }
            ।
            %
            \pend%
            % %\par%
            % %
            \pstart%
            %
            \textbf{ननु} न प्रतिबन्धकाभावस्य कारणता ;
            प्रतिबन्धापेक्षः \edtext{तदभावः}{%
                %\lemma{}%
                \Bfootnote{%
                    प्रतिबन्धाभावः ।%
                }%
            }
            कारणं ,
            कारणापेक्षश्च \edtext{तदभावः}{%
                %\lemma{}%
                \Bfootnote{%
                    \textbf{कारणाभावः} = प्रतिबन्धाभावरूपं यत् कारणं तदभावः ।%
                }%
            }
            प्रतिबन्ध
            \edtext{इत्यन्योन्याश्रयग्रस्तत्वात्}{%
                %\lemma{}%
                \Bfootnote{%
                    अयं कारणप्रतिबन्धकयोः ज्ञप्तौ अन्योन्याश्रयः ।%
                }%
            }
            ,
            \edtext{प्रतिबन्धो विसामग्री , तद्धेतुः प्रतिबन्धक}{%
                %\lemma{}%
                \Bfootnote{%
                    \textbf{विसामग्री} = सामग्र्यभावः ।\\
                    \textbf{तद्धेतुः} = सामग्रीवैकल्यहेतुः ।%
                }%
            }
            \edtext{इत्यङ्गीकाराद्}{%
                %\lemma{}%
                \Bfootnote{%
                    उदयनाचार्य्यादिभिः त्वन्मतीयैः इत्यादि ।%
                }%
            }
            \textbf{इति चेत्} ।%
            %
            \pend%
            % %\\
            % %
            \pstart%
            %
            \textbf{मैवम्} ; अवधीर्यैव \edtext{अभावस्य}{%
                %\lemma{}%
                \Bfootnote{%
                    प्रतिबन्धकाभावस्य ।%
                }%
            }
            कारणतां कार्यानुदयमात्रेणैव मन्त्रादेः \edtext{कार्यप्रतिकूलतावगमात्}{%
                %\lemma{}%
                \Bfootnote{%
                    प्रतिबन्धकत्वज्ञानात् ।%
                }%
            }
            ,
            अनवलम्ब्यैव च मणिमन्त्रादेः कार्यप्रतिबन्धकत्वं \edtext{तदभावस्य}{%
                %\lemma{}%
                \Bfootnote{%
                    मणिमन्त्राद्यभावस्य ।%
                }%
            }
            अन्वयव्यतिरेकाभ्यामेव कारणताध्यवसायात् ।
            %
            \pend%
            % %\par%
            % %
            \pstart%
            %
            % प्रतिबन्धकाभावकारणयोरन्योन्याश्रयस्य परिहारः ।
            किञ्च \edtext{\textbf{अन्योन्याश्रयत्वम्}}{%
                %\lemma{}%
                \Bfootnote{%
                    प्रतिबन्धकाभावकारणयोः ।%
                }%
            }
            \textbf{उत्पत्तौ} , \textbf{ज्ञप्तौ} वा स्यात् ।\\
            \textbf{नाद्यः} ; \edtext{मन्त्रतदभावयोः}{%
                %\lemma{}%
                \Bfootnote{%
                    प्रतिबन्धकस्य मन्त्रादेः तदभावरूपकारणस्य च उत्पत्तौ परस्परानपेक्षत्वात् नाद्यकल्पः , न हि प्रतिबन्धकोपादानकस्य तदभावः , तदभावोपादनको वा प्रतिबन्धक इति ।%
                }%
            }
            परस्परहेतुत्वाभावात् ।\\
            \textbf{नापि द्वितीयः} ; अज्ञातयोरपि मन्त्रतदभावयोः कार्यं प्रति प्रतिकूलत्वकारणत्वयोरुपपत्तेः ।
            %
            \pend%
            % %\par%
            % % 
            % %
            \pstart%
            %
            \textbf{ननु} \edtext{कार्याभावावसेयकार्यप्रतिकूलभावा}{%
                %\lemma{}%
                \Bfootnote{%
                    कार्य्याभावान्यथानुपपत्त्या कार्य्यप्रतिकूलत्वं ज्ञातं येषां ते मन्त्रादयः ।%
                }%
            }
            \edtext{मन्त्रादयः}{%
                %\lemma{}%
                \Bfootnote{%
                    प्रतिबन्धकाः ।%
                }%
            }
            \edtext{शक्तेः अपह्नवाय}{%
                %\lemma{}%
                \Bfootnote{%
                    शक्त्यङ्गीकारपरिहाराय ।%
                }%
            }
            कारणाभावरूपा इष्यन्ते ,
            अत एव \edtext{मन्त्राद्यभावोऽपि}{%
                %\lemma{}%
                \Bfootnote{%
                    प्रतिबन्धकाभावः ।%
                }%
            }
            कारणम् इष्यते ।
            ततो मन्त्रतदभावनिष्ठप्रतिबन्धकत्वकारणत्वयोः अन्योन्योपाधिकत्वाद् उत्पत्तौ ज्ञप्तौ वा अन्योन्याश्रयता दुर्वारा\textbf{ इति चेत्} ।
            %
            \pend%
            % %\\
            % %
            \pstart%
            %
            \textbf{न} ;
            \edtext{उक्तोत्तरत्वात्}{%
                %\lemma{}%
                \Bfootnote{%
                    ?????%
                }%
            }
            ---
            अन्तरेणैवाभावस्य कारणतावगमं मन्त्रादेः कार्याभावमात्रेण कार्यप्रतिकूलभावस्यावगन्तुं शक्यत्वात् ,
            तदभावकारणत्वस्यापि अन्वयव्यतिरेकाभ्यामेव सुकरावगमत्वात्
            --- इति ।%
            %
            \pend%
            %\par%%
        \end{quoting}%
        %
        \pstart%
        %
        % शक्त्यनङ्गीकारेपि कार्य्योपपत्तेरुपपादनम् ।
        \textbf{न च} --- शक्त्यनङ्गीकारे प्रतिबन्धासम्भवः , मणिमन्त्रादिसन्निधानासन्निधानयोः \edtext{स्वरूपस्य}{%
            %\lemma{}%
            \Bfootnote{%
                कारणस्वरूपस्य ।%
            }%
        }
        अविशेषाद् --- \textbf{इति वाच्यं} ;\\
        कार्यौदासीन्यस्यैव प्रतिबन्धशब्दाभिधेयस्य विशेषत्वात् ।\\
        अन्यथा , शक्तिपक्षेऽपि प्रतिबन्धस्य दुर्विवेकत्वात् ।%
        %
        \pend%
        %
        \begin{quoting}%
            %
            \pstart%
            %
            न हि शक्तेर्नाशः प्रतिबन्धः ; प्रतिबन्धापाये कार्याभावप्रसङ्गात् ।\\
            न च स्फोटाख्यकार्योत्पत्तये शक्त्यन्तरं तत्रोत्पन्नं ; तत्कारणानिरूपणात् ।\\
            न च प्रतिबन्धाभावः कारणम् ;
            अभावस्य कारणतानङ्गीकारात् ;
            अङ्गीकारे वा तस्यैव स्फोटादिकार्यजनकत्वम् अस्तु ,
            कृतम् अतीन्द्रियशक्तिकल्पनादुर्व्यसनेन ।\\
            शक्तेः शक्त्यन्तरं प्रतिषध्यते इति वदतोऽनवस्था ।\\
            तस्मात् कार्यस्य अन्यथापि उपपन्नत्वात् न अतीन्द्रियशक्तिकल्पनावकाशः ।%
            %
            \pend%
            %
        \end{quoting}%
        %% 
    \end{quoting}%
    % 
    \pstart%
\end{chitsukhI}%
% 
% 
% 
\endnumbering%
% 
% 
% 
\end{document}
```

If you remove the \pstart and \pend, as is shown in the MWE and use the single \pstart and \pend provided by the custom env `chitsukhI` , then it complies. But, line numbers are not correct. See the screenshot :
[image]

I know that using \par is useless and I've to use pair of \pstart and \pend. So, if I enable those commands, the compilation fails and log file says :

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.358 ^^I^^I\end{quoting}
                         %
```

So, I counted the number of \pstart and \pend, including those inside the custom env `chitsukhI`. The number is same for \pstart and \pend, but the compilation still fails with the mentioned error.